# Sheetrock.js - trouble setting sumif query: "select A, sum(C) where sumif(C > 50)"

Tags: javascript, sheetrock

Trying to make a query via sheetrock.js for sumif:

```
$('#classes').sheetrock({
  url : spreadsheet, 
  query: "select sum(C) where sumif(C > 50)",
  headersOff : true,
});
```

I have a table where the A column has tasks names and C column has hours as numbers, I need to grab tasks that in sum are less than 40, than again tasks that are less than 40 and on down the list, to see what tasks will fill in a 40-hrs working week. Overall, I was only able to get the sum of all the tasks, like so: query: "select sum(D) where A contains 'iOS'"; however, I need now to get the tasks by week. Is it possible? Thank you for any response!

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I have a table where the A column has tasks names and C column has hours as numbers, I need to grab tasks that in sum are less than 40, than again tasks that are less than 40 and on down the list, to see what tasks will fill in a 40-hrs working week. Overall, I was only able to get the sum of all the tasks, like so: query: "select sum(D) where A contains 'iOS'"; however, I need now to get the tasks by week. Is it possible, @Michał Młoźniak Thank you for any response!

Comment: Please edit your question and put this clarification there, not in the comment. You will have better chance getting some answers. Thanks.